# Significant difference in measuring the performance of a method in an isolated script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm optimizing my code that is part of a larger environment with hundreds of classes etc. So I extracted the problematic method and created a simple script in order to measure the performance of this method.

I found that I should optimize the method by simply returning False from is_intersect() method instead of calculating then returning. By doing that, the execution time of my program went from 25s to 12s.

I was surprised to see that when I created the script and called the method alone 1M times, the execution time was only ~1s. My original program has a loop with ~2.5k iterations for this example. So I'm profiling with 400 times the number of the original loop and it's taking 11s less to execute?

Benchmark:

```
  original program: 
    n of loops: 2.5k
    execution time=25s
    execution time after replacing the problematic function by a constant = 12s

    n of loops: 10k
    execution time=21m30s
    execution time after replacing the problematic function by a constant = 46s

  external script (single file) shown below: 
    n of loops: 10k
    execution time: <1s

    n of loops: 1M
    execution time: ~1s
```

#### Original program:

I modified the original names and inserted some comments that may help to understand what each method does. For this example the functionality is very simple:

The program is scanning an image of the sky with step X and step Y. If it finds a star that intersects with another object (space monkey if you wish). Not the best example but I think it may help :)

```py
def my_original_method(self):
    for pos_xy_key, pos_xy_tuple in self.pos_xy.items():  # size of pos_xy is 2.5k items with tuples (float*8 items)
        # e.g. poly1_xmin_xmax = [125, 500]
        # poly1_ymin_ymax = [60, 600]
        # These values change on each iteration, they never repeat
        poly1_xmin_xmax, poly1_ymin_ymax = modules.utils.polygon_from_pos_xy(pos_xy_tuple)
    
        for name in self.stars:  # self.stars is a dict() with 1k items
            parent_name = self.stars[name]['parent']
            if name in self.set_with_names:  # size of set is around 20k items
                # e.g. poly2_xmin_xmax = [1, 2]
                # poly2_ymin_ymax = [1, 2]
                # These values change on each iteration, they may repeat
                # return the absolute value of the star in space
                poly2_xmin_xmax,  poly2_ymin_ymax = self.polygon_star(name, parent_name)  

                # if False:  # this reduces the execution time from 25s to 12s
                if modules.utils.is_intersect(polygon_particle, polygon_cell):
                    self.results[name] = True
```

#### Script for the problematic method

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        print('hello')

    def is_intersect(self, poly1_xmin_xmax, poly1_ymin_ymax, poly2_xmin_xmax, poly2_ymin_ymax):
        if min(poly1_xmin_xmax) > max(poly2_xmin_xmax) or max(poly1_xmin_xmax) < min(poly2_xmin_xmax):
            return False
        if min(poly1_ymin_ymax) > max(poly2_ymin_ymax) or max(poly1_ymin_ymax) < min(poly2_ymin_ymax):
            return False
        return True

obj_test = Test()

poly1_xmin_xmax = [125, 500]
poly1_ymin_ymax = [60, 600]

temp_dct = dict()

for i in range(1000000):
    poly1_xmin_xmax = [125, 5000]
    poly1_ymin_ymax = [60, 2000]
    poly2_xmin_xmax = [i+1, i+1]
    poly2_ymin_ymax = [61, 500]
    if obj_test.is_intersect(poly1_xmin_xmax, poly1_ymin_ymax, poly2_xmin_xmax, poly2_ymin_ymax):
        temp_dct[i] = True
```

I thought the problem had something to do with function overhead but apparently not since I calculated the intersection directly inside the loop and the execution time was still around 25s.

Any ideas why there's a difference in the execution time of my method inside my original code and inside a separated script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original program has two **nested** loops, with the outer one being run 2500 times and the inner one being run 1000 times **in every iteration of the outer loop**. So the code inside the inner loop is run **2.5 M** times.

Comment: How stupid of me. I must be tired :) That was the issue.

Comment: Don't fret, just a moment ago I insisted that 66/11 == 5 :-)

Comment: And it isn't? ;) Thanks